# Get only individual user and admin conversation in user dashboard using socket io chat

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, model-view-controller, socket.io

I am using socket io chat for making interface between user and admin. I have include socket library in my view code and implemented it on user dashboard.Now currently i am getting conversation between all users and admin in user individual chat box. While sending message from user to admin it working fine only conversation between that user and admin is with in one chat room in admin panel. How can i get chat between individual user and admin in user dashboard.

view code:

```
<script>
    var localuserid = '<%-user.id%>';
     var socket = io()
    socket.on("chat", addChat)

    $(() => {
        getChats()
    $("#send").click((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var chatMessage = {
                 chat: $('#btn-chat-input').val(),
                 userid: $('#userid').val(),
                 role: 'user',
                 sender: $('#userid').val(),
                 msg_desc: $('#btn-chat-input').val(),
                 reciever: $('#adminid').val()

              }
            //console.log(chat);
            postChat(chatMessage);
            addChat(chatMessage);
            $('#btn-chat-input').val();

        });
    })

    function postChat(chat) {
    $.post("/saveuserchat", chat)
    }


    function getChats() {
        $.get("/getuserchat", (chats) => {
            //console.log(chats);
     chats.forEach(addChat)
      })
    }
    function addChat(chatObj) {

    $("#chat_message").append(`<p class="usermsg">${chatObj.msg_desc}</p>`);

    }
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/getuserchat?senderid="+localuserid,
           success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
           }
        })



</script>
```

controller code:

```
app.get('/getuserchat',isLoggedIn,function(req, res) {
   // var senderId = req.param("senderid");
chat.find({}, function(error, chats){
    console.log(chats);
        res.send(chats);
    });
   });
```